# Difference in n = (n * (n + 1)) // 2 and n = (n * (n + 1)) / 2; n = int(n)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am new to competitive programming and python. I was trying this question on codechef, https://www.codechef.com/CCSTART2/problems/ADDNATRL which requires me to find the sum of first N natural numbers.

this was my first solution:

```
n = int(input())
n = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
print(int(n))
```

This gave me a Wrong Answer [WA].

While the below solution was Accepted,

```
n = int(input())
n = (n * (n + 1)) // 2
print(n)
```

so I was wondering what the actual difference is since both gave me the same output in my local machine.

Comment: Do they give the same answer for negative numbers?

Comment: @sabik I believe the problem statement implies that `n` is natural.

Comment: @VishalSingh `//` performs ground division which means that it divides and then rounds down to the nearest integer. (two integers divided could form a float btw)

Comment: If it's not negative numbers, it'll be very large ones, where the floating point rounding becomes a problem

Comment: Right, the problem statement excludes both negative and very large numbers; it's not either of those, then

Comment: Actually, it probably is large numbers; 1e18 is big enough to give rounding errors

Comment: Don't forget the intermediate value, which is 1e18

Comment: If `n` is large, floating point division will introduce rounding error, due to the fixed-size, binary floating point format. `//` will always be correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/` gives the quotient as a float while `//` gives integer result.

At the upper end of the range for n, `1e9`, the intermediate result of around `1e18` cannot be represented exactly in an IEEE "double" float, which is what python usually uses, and suffers rounding error. An approximate answer is output.

Meanwhile the range for integers is unlimited, so the exact answer is output.

For example:

```
>>> n = 999999998
>>> int((n * (n + 1)) / 2)
499999998500000000
>>> (n * (n + 1)) // 2
499999998500000001
>>>
```

Answer (score -3):

`/` gives the remainder in float while `//` gives integer result.

`//` is same as the `/` in other programming or scripting languages.

But in Python `/` is introduced as division that gives a integer output and `//` is floor division that gives integer output

As in competitive programming, the best way is taken. You can use `//` other than using `/` and `int()`. This reduces running time also

Comment: I'm not sure `k//2` is necessarily faster than `int(k/2)`; floating-point math is often hardware-accelerated while arbitrary precision integers are not. You'd have to measure to be sure...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is not about the difference between `//` and `/` in general, but about the different behavior of the two specific expressions.